# how to perform addition/multiplication on the textboxes that are appear in loop?

Tags: php, javascript

hi everryone my promblem is that i apply loop on one row of table ,the exceution of loop depends on the user input in the text mean whatever the number user write in the textbox repective number of rows will be display.Now each row contain textbox,comboxbox on selcting value from combobox n entering value in textbox from first three column ,result will display.The promblem is ths that ths condition only in the first row nt in second row .what can i do to overcome ths.

javascriptng code

```
<script>
function getText3(){
var in1=document.getElementById('in1').value;
var in2=document.getElementById('in2').value;
var in4=document.getElementById('in4').value;
var in3=(in1*in2*in4*30)/1000;
document.getElementById('in3').value=in3.toFixed(2 );

}
</script>
```

here i get the value of combobox n textbox by their ids n store the result in other textbox i.e in3

coding of table

```
</head>
<body>


 <table border="1" align="center" id="wr123">
        <?php $numberofrow = $de;?>
<?php for($counter = 1;$counter<=$numberofrow;$counter++){ ?>
<tr>
    <th>WAS</th>
    <th>NO.</th>
    <th>AVERAGE</th>
    <th>APPROX</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Tube</td>
    <td>
    <select id="in4" name="t1" onclick="getText3()" >
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="75">75</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="t2" id="in1" onclick="getText3()" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <select name="a1" id="in2" onclick="getText3()" >
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" id="in3" name="username" readonly="readonly" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <tr>
    <?php }?>
```

result is display like ths

WAS     NO.     AVERAGE     APPROX

2   3    4          result display here

WAS     NO.     AVERAGE     APPROX

2   3   4       no result

Comment: How is this related to `PHP` ?

Comment: sir kindly help me for thsi task

Comment: ^ exactly and as a new user, you never post long codes. it always get downvoted, by the xperts with 100k's and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
   function getText3(row){
            var in1=document.getElementById('in1-' + row).value;
            var in2=document.getElementById('in2-' + row).value;
            var in4=document.getElementById('in4-' + row).value;
            var in3=(in1*in2*in4*30)/1000;
            document.getElementById('in3-' + row).value=in3.toFixed(2 );

    }
```

And this for the HTML / PHP

```
<table border="1" align="center" id="wr123">
    <tr>
        <th>WAS</th>
        <th>NO.</th>
        <th>AVERAGE</th>
        <th>APPROX</th>
    </tr>
    <?php

    for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Tube</td>
        <td>
            <select id="in4-<?php echo $i; ?>" name="t1[]" onclick="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)" >
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="75">75</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="t2[]" id="in1-<?php echo $i; ?>" onblur="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="a1[]" id="in2-<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="getText3(<?php echo $i; ?>)" >
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="in3-<?php echo $i; ?>" name="username[]" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sir can i pass different rows value on next page by post method in php?

Comment: Yes, change the names to use the "a1[]" rather than just "a1".

Comment: where i should change the name

Comment: Modified my code so you can see.

Comment: sir i have modify in the similar manner bt when i get post on next page it dont display value code is <?php
@$a=$_POST['t1'];
echo @$a;
$sl = $_POST['t2'];
echo $sl;
$b=$_POST['a1'];
echo $b;
$c=$_POST['username'];
echo $c;


?>

Comment: We should probably continue this in [chat]

Comment: sir actually i am new in ths form kindly if u dont mind then answer me here sir kindly consider ths http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750278/how-to-pass-value-of-for-loop-from-one-page-to-next-page-in-php?noredirect=1#comment24127431_16750278